# How do I get my system to recognize an external drive and automount it?

Tags: mount, external-hdd, gvfs

I have an external drive (regular hard drive in a portable USB sled), which is definitely being detected by my system:

```
[17444.585104] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[17444.607892] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=a003
[17444.607897] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17444.607899] usb 2-1: Product: USB
[17444.607901] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[17444.607904] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: [redacted]
[17444.621921] scsi host3: uas
[17444.623400] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  USB              0836 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[17447.781513] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[17447.782315] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029167 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[17447.782740] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[17447.782744] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2b 00 10 08
[17447.783552] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[17447.804606]  sdb: sdb1
[17447.807607] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

However, there is no indication in the UI that such a drive exists. If I want to use my drive, I have to manually mount it from the terminal, or use manually-defined `fstab` rules.

Ideally, I'd like to get this USB hard drive to be treated the same way as any flash drive. Namely, I insert the drive and the system auto-mounts it and presents it to me in the UI and is immediately accessible, like so:

[image: My drive is mounted!]

From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101074/how-does-mounting-on-the-gui-work-under-the-hood), I understand that it works on GVFS and the FUSE system, but this doesn't exactly help me get the behavior I want.

So, what can I do to get my external drive be treated the same as any USB flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

You can always set it up in the `/etc/fstab` file, and add on the `nofail` option so that if it is not attached during boot it won't fail and hang there.

Here's an example of my 3TB external drive:

```
UUID=6AAA4323AA42EB61 /media/Seagate ntfs defaults,nofail 0 0
```

When the system boots if the drive is offline, there are no errors at all.  When I power it on or plug it in, it will still automatically mount in that exact same location.

Hope this helps!

Comment: in the preference for nautilus, there is an automount option. setting to true will allow all plug in media to be automounted.

Comment: One of the things I'd like to avoid *is* the use of `/etc/fstab`. If the system can be handled by FUSE instead, it would be much more preferential (less messing around with permissions and the like). I will take this into account and use it until I have a more solid solution though, thanks.

Comment: @KazWolfe No problem.  I get exactly what you are saying.  I was trying to figure it out on my 3TB external, and I was following what someone else posted online about using FUSE and udisks for automounting.  I had a solution using udev that seemed to work, but it wasn't recommended.  So I did the udisks trick, and the drive didn't fully mount at startup like it was supposed to until I clicked on it in a file manager.  I hope someone shows a good way for this to work without the fstab.  Until then, I am keeping my own solution.  =)